# How to calculate the force required to move this water bot with certain speed

Tags: mechanical-engineering, water-resources, thrust

This is my project where I have created a river cleaning machine. It works fine but no actual calculations have been done regarding the power requirement of motors(A software engineer ). The machine is half-submerged in water.

I want to know how to calculate the total amount for the force required to move this machine. Is there any formula that tells how much force is required to exceed the resistance of water and attain a certain speed.

*Kindly ignore the white PVC pipes attached on the side of the machine. I added that because of some balancing issues which I will solve and thus the pipes will be removed.*

My target is that even if I make a bigger model then using these same calculations I should be able to select the motor accordingly.

Waiting for your amazing answers. :)[image: River cleaning project]

Comment: What research have you dine and what have you found? There is plenty of information about this...

Comment: @SolarMike That's what am struggling with. Because the calculations are available for boats that float on the water but my case is different. My machine is half submerged.

Comment: Boats have some part underwater... or did you not get that? Check out Archimedes..

Comment: The drag coefficient is the key, you need to find it out. The rest is then not so difficult .